# Cannot implilcitly convert type int? to int when retrieving and int field value from LINQ expression

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get an int value from a table based on another ID, I'm using EF to do this but I'm getting the error that cannot implicitly convert type int? to int. This field allow null values.

```
public int GetIDFunctionRT(int id)
{
  var mRT = context.OrgFunctions.First(bf => bf.FormerID == id);
  return mRT.IDF;
}
```

I have tried to include ?mRT to deal with the Nullable but not working.

```
public int GetIDFunctionRT(int id)
{
  var mRT = context.OrgFunctions.First(bf => bf.FormerID == id);
  return mRT.IDF;
}
```

Once done, I will get the function ID associated with an id in another table.

Comment: Have you tried `fb.FormerID.Value == id` ?

Comment: If IDF is nullable int type, then you can do return mRT.IDF.HasValue ? mRT.IDF.Value : 0;

Comment: Have you tried making the return type nullable(public int?)?

Comment: Thanks Xiaosu it was really helpful...

Comment: I will go with @Xiaosu 's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated, return type of method is int, yet you are returning int?.
Also, your First may throw an exception if nothing is there.
In order to make it predictable, I'll use FirstOrDefault

```
public int? GetIDFunctionRT(int id)
{
  var mRT = context.OrgFunctions.FirstOrDefault(bf => bf.FormerID == id);
  return mRT?.IDF.HasValue ? mRT?.IDF : 0;
}
```

Comment: Good catch, I changed

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to approach this.

Make the return type Nullable. You can do so by changing the return type to `int?`

```
public int? GetIDFunctionRT(int id)
{
  var mRT = context.OrgFunctions.First(bf => bf.FormerID == id);
  return mRT.IDF;
}
```

Return `int` but assign a default value if it is null.

```
public int GetIDFunctionRT(int id)
{
  var mRT = context.OrgFunctions.First(bf => bf.FormerID == id);
  // Where DefaultValue is the value you want to return when it is null, 
  // could be 0 or anything else depending on your logic.
  return mRT.IDF ?? DefaultValue;
}
```

Comment: Check your second option again please!